# Determine a matrix given eigenvalues and single eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Anyway, say there is some original matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ that you are trying to reconstruct.  Also let $M$ be symmetric and positive-definite.  You have at your disposal $\Lambda$, a diagonal matrix who contains its eigenvalues and only a single normalized eigenvector, a column vector $v_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$.  Originally I thought it would be possible because the eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix are orthogonal, so we could just find a basis for the null space of $v_1$.

For example do an singular value decomposition of **$v_1$** so $v_1=USV$ where obviously $V=1$, as $v_1^Tv_1=1$ since $v_1$ is normalized.  Also $v_1$ can only have rank $1$, so $S=[1,0,0,\ldots,0]^T$.  Lastly we consider $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, found from eigenvectors of $v_1v_1^T$, which should be orthogonal as $v_1v_1^T$ is also symmetric. Breaking $U$ into column vectors gives $U=[u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n]$.  See $v_1=u_1$ as
$$v_1 = [u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n] \cdot [1,0,0,\ldots,0]^T\cdot1=u_1.$$

Thus, since $u_2,\ldots,u_n$ are orthogonal to $u_1$, and therefore $v_1$, we have a set of orthogonal vectors we could potentially use to reconstruct $M$ by its diagonalization, so
$$M=U\cdot\Lambda\cdot U^T.$$

Thoughts on why this process is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Given $\Lambda$ and $v_1$, construct $M$" is your question in short. 
Let $\lambda_k$ and $v_k$ be the $k^{th}$ eigenpair. $M$ is written as $$M = \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \lambda_k v_kv_k^T$$
In the above equation, you have $\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_N$ and $v_1$; for complete reconstruction, you need $v_2 \ldots v_N$.

Comment: You could get away with $v_2\ldots v_{N-1}$, since the $v_i$ are orthonormal.

Comment: How can you do this @SeanLake

Comment: @ElBazzi If you have $v_1,\ldots,v_{N-1}$ there are only two ways to choose a unit vector $v_N$ orthogonal to $v_1,\ldots,v_{N-1}$, and these two choices differ by sign (which doesn't affect your formula for $M$).

Comment: Given $N-1$ linearly independent vectors in an $N$ dimensional vector space you can construct a vector independent of all of the $N-1$ vectors by either applying Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization with a lucky guess, or setting up a determinant of a matrix where the first row is the basis vectors, and the other rows are the components of the $N-1$ independent vectors (see: [multilinear algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra) ).

Comment: 1)You could construct many orthonormal basis
2)We all know that, but which vector corresponds to which eigenvalue ?

Comment: Which vector corresponds with which eigenvalue is an unanswered question even if you have all $N$ vectors. So the $N-1$ vectors have to be explicitly tied to $N-1$ of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I might have explained myself wrong, let's say you have a rotated ellipsoid. Can you tell me, given one axis (which is $v_1$), how can you determine all other axes that support this ellipsoid. Say $v_1 = e_1$ (the x-axis), Gram-Schmidt gives you $v_2 = e_2$ and $v_3 = e_3$ (maybe), but that is not necessarily true.

Comment: If you give me $N-1$ of the axes, and the length of all of the semi-axes, I can find the last axis, up to an irrelevant sign error. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I did not know you meant that since you said in the beginning "you could get away with $v_2 \ldots v_{N-1}$

Comment: Misunderstanding because I was trying to correct the phrase, "you need $v_2\ldots v_N$."

Comment: I should learn to wait 5 min before i reply to comments..This is my fault.